# Trig Bearing Problem

Tags: trigonometry

Help! This question is driving me mental! I am stuck on part b...

[click here to view question http://pinkpixel.com.au/wp-content/uploads/Q1.jpg](http://pinkpixel.com.au/wp-content/uploads/Q1.jpg)

Anyone have any hints please?

Comment: The picture isnt loading..

Comment: Hi Zhoe, can you see it now? I just added a different picture.

Comment: I don't know if this is right but wouldn't it just be 36 degrees North of East?

Comment: You should post some of you work, what have you tried and how do you think you would go about solving it. This site is not for answers to homework problems, rather giving you the mathematical insight you need to solve it.

Comment: Yeah, the problem with that is I don't know where to start and my textbook has no examples of questions similar to this. I am getting so frustrated... I just can't find anything even remotely similar to give me any ideas.

Comment: Plus I didn't ask for an answer... I asked for hints...

Comment: Fair enough: I'm assuming that you used the law of cosines to solve part a. With that you have a vector going from the square to the triangle, correct?

Comment: Yes, I managed to get the distance from triangle marker to square marker as 28.59m (using c^2=a^2+b^2-a(ab)(cos29) -(who knows this is probably wrong too!) Argh!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

b) Extend the laser vector through the right channel marker until it hits the 
horizontal line through the left channel marker; it will make an angle of $36^{\circ}$ with this line.

Next use the Law of Sines to find the angle between the laser vector through the left channel marker and the line segment between the two channel markers.

Comment: So, just to make sure I have this correct...

Comment: ![question edited](http://pinkpixel.com.au/wp-content/uploads/Q1-2.jpg)

Comment: ok so images don't work in comments - could you look at the image and let me know if I'm on the right track?
http://pinkpixel.com.au/wp-content/uploads/Q1-2.jpg

Comment: @Jen No, this isn't exactly what I meant; first extend the laser through the right channel marker until its hits the line going east from the left channel marker.

Comment: is this what you mean? http://pinkpixel.com.au/wp-content/uploads/Q1-3.jpg (blue line) If so, which angle is 36 degrees? and which angle do I need to find?

Comment: @Jen If you draw a line perpendicular to the blue line that goes through the left channel marker, the right laser will make an angle of $36^{\circ}$ with this line.

Comment: Oh man I feel so dumb! I just don't get this. Is this what your talking about? http://pinkpixel.com.au/wp-content/uploads/Q1-4.jpg

Comment: So which angle do I need to find (if this is what you mean)

Comment: @Jen Yes, you have it right; now draw the line segment between the channel markers, and find the angle between this segment and the left laser.

Comment: so like this? http://pinkpixel.com.au/wp-content/uploads/Q1-5.jpg

Comment: anyone? help? please?

Comment: @Jen You want to find the angle you have marked with ???, so first find the angle between the line segment from part a) and the left laser.